# Is it possible to setup a Allure reporting server?

Tags: automated-testing, java, test-report, spa, allure

we have various teams across our business unit. I need to consolidate the test results across the teams and display for Business unit leads. So we were thinking allocate a AWS S3 storage location and consolidate all the reports there. Is it possible ?

Comment: How do you run the tests currently?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? The question as it stands is either too broad or only gets a yes/no answers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably. [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) is an open-source project. So you can change the code and decide where to store the results.

Also if you can export the report you could manually store it on S3.

Comment: hi all Why is the question negative any idea